# Errors were encountered while processing: ec2-instance-connect

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been trying to install docker on my WSL and it is constantly throwing an error

I've tried `sudo apt-get remove ec2-instance-connect` and it is throwing this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ec2-instance-connect
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 57.3 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 64032 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing ec2-instance-connect (1.1.12+dfsg1-0ubuntu3) ...
Deleted system user ec2-instance-connect
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
dpkg: error processing package ec2-instance-connect (--remove):
 installed ec2-instance-connect package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ec2-instance-connect
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It is not allowing me to run an `upgrade` or `install` any new packages.

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 4):

I just ran across someone else with pretty much the [same issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/663668/432493) on the Unix & Linux Stack.  When looking for an answer, I just found this (unanswered) question.  I posted an answer there, but I'll repeat the relevant parts for this question in case anyone else comes across it.

`ec2-instance-connect` turns out to be a pretty problematic package if installed erroneously on WSL.  It should typically only be installed on Ubuntu when running in an Amazon/AWS EC2 instance.

It has both a post-install and post-remove script that assume Systemd, which isn't available on WSL.  As far as I can tell, since the `postinstall` never completes successfully, it attempts to run every time you do many other `apt` commands.

To get rid of it (and stop the errors), it's not enough to `sudo apt purge ec2-instance-connect`, because the post-remove errors will still fail (and the package will remain).  You'll need to:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/ec2-instance-connect.postrm
sudo apt purge ec2-instance-connect
sudo deluser --system --quiet ec2-instance-connect
```

`apt` should be working properly again after this, but please see the Unix & Linux Stack answer linked above for some discussion on other things to check that may need to be cleaned up.